# restrict permissions on Facebook

Tags: facebook, node.js, mongodb, facebook-graph-api, passport-facebook

Developing an app using node.js, mongodb, express and using passport to autheticate users on facebook , I would like to know if I can restrict "default permissions" to login on facebook,

this is the function to call facebook API

```
function facebookSignIn(req, res, next) {
    passport = req._passport.instance;
    passport.authenticate('facebook', function(err, user, info) {
    })(req,res,next);
};
```

and after this request, facebook API responses with an advice message:

> MyAPP will receive the following information from you: public profile and friends list.

and I would like only the public profile and not the friends list.

Desired message:

> MyAPP will receive the following information from you: public profile

Answer (score 0):

The friendlist is the part of default permission you can't supress it/

If you check the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/), it says-

> The default includes some basic attributes about the person and a list of friends. The default permissions are included as part of every permissions request